# How does docker container find local host IP address in Mac?

Tags: docker

I am using docker for mac and want to get local mac IP address inside a docker container. I know that I can run `ifconfig` on mac and get the IP `lo0`. But I want to know whether I can get this IP inside the container instead of running command on host machine.

**EDIT1**

I want to write a script in that container to find the mac host address dynamically. So I don't want to use a hard coded one. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Would you try to communicate from container with mac host? If yes you can use a docker virtual device for comunicate from container to host. Usually the ip address is `172.17.0.1`.

Comment: How can I check the IP address inside the container. What I am going to do is to write  a script in that container to find the IP dynamically. So I don't want to use a hard coded one.

Comment: You can run a container with env variable with host IP `-e "DOCKER_HOST=$(ip -4 addr show eth0| grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')`.

Comment: Actually I want to find it inside the container instead of outside.